# How to show general DB characteristic

Tags: python, postgresql

I am looking for database data such as Database Name, Database Location, Database Type, Access Driver. How to find the location of the database (on the server) and the access driver.

`query = ''' SELECT datname, cast(datname as text) AS database_path, datctype, pg_catalog.pg_database_driver(datname::text) AS drivername FROM pg_catalog.pg_database '''`

Comment: What are Database Location and Database Type?

Comment: On postgresql you can ask with \l command.

Comment: @Hermann12 I’m trying to find the path to the data files that the cluster uses by querying. Or this path can not be obtained using this method (queue)

Comment: For the path use `show data_directory;`